# How Can I Extract The Year From Object Column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-extraction

So I have a data frame in python. I want to make a new column that has solely the year from the column found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKrSB.png).

The column is not in datetime format or anything due to the country listed at the tail end and I've tried using split() like so:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column_name'].astype(str).split(",", 3)[2]
```

but apparently, that doesn't work on objects.

Again, the columns are listed like so:

```
October 1, 2020 (United States) 
April 27, 2019 (Cameroon)
```

but are type object and not string.

It is primarily the differing lengths in the countries at the end that has kept me from pulling from index like so:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column_name'].astype(str).str[x:x]
```

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried using [RegEx's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: Are you using pandas? If so, you can check [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: @ErselEr I am using pandas, yea.

Comment: Can you chage the tags of the question. This is not related to `anaconda`. Pls add `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a column to `datetime` with [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). You can:

1. pass the `format` as strftime. Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).
2. If you do not know the format, you can use `infer_datetime_format=True`. However be careful while using this parameter, because it may convert in wrong order.

After that year can be extracted as follows:

```
# Create sample df:
df = pd.DataFrame({
       'id': [1, 2], 
       'date': [
         'April 27, 2019 (Cameroon)', 
         'October 1, 2020 (United States)'
       ]
})
# Remove country names
df['new_date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(' (')[0])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id                             date         new_date
0   1        April 27, 2019 (Cameroon)   April 27, 2019
1   2  October 1, 2020 (United States)  October 1, 2020
```

Then `new_date` can be converted to datetime:

```
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   id        2 non-null      int64         
 1   date      2 non-null      object        
 2   new_date  2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
```

Then we can extract year from `new_date`:

```
df['year'] = df['new_date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

Here is the final `df`:

```
   id                             date   new_date  year
0   1        April 27, 2019 (Cameroon) 2019-04-27  2019
1   2  October 1, 2020 (United States) 2020-10-01  2020
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me! I'm a little confused on how DateTime can be used when the country is also included in the same element though?

Comment: Country can be discarded by using a simple `str.split()` funcition or using regex. I have just updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why:
df['new_column'] = df['column_name'].astype(str).split(",", 3)[2]
doesn't work? They both make use of splits but I don't understand. I'm new to python.

Comment: `df['column_name']` is the whole column (series in pandas) and `.split()` is defined on strings not for [pandas series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). What you wanted to do is to `.split()` each row in `column_name`. In order to do that pandas has methods such as `apply()`. You can check it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).